# State parameter shows compile error on Creating Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, taskfactory

I have created a simple `Task` instance in my code and i want to pass `index` as the `State` parameter for that `Task`. I have wrote the following code to archive this. But not working. Can anyone please help me on this?. Thanks in Advance.

```
int index = 0;
Task<int> task = new Task<int>(() =>
{
   return 1;
}, index);

task.Start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass `state` parameter to your Task , then your delegate (first argument) should accept this state parameter as its input:

```
int index = 0;
Task<int> task = new Task<int>((state) => { return 1; }, index);
//Task<int> task = new Task<int>(state => 1, index); // a bit shorter alternative

task.Start();
```

Comment: @Yurivy Will Task.ContinueWith also work like above?

Comment: It depends on the kind of task you want to execute in `ContinueWith` method, but one thing for sure it should at least accept the previous task as its argument.